# Importar datos Laravel Excel con Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy realizando un CRUD para proyecto de la escuela con Laravel y Vue, el detalle es que también debo de importar un Excel en x extensión (CSV, XSLS, etc), solo que no he podido hacer que lea mi excel, les muestro mi codigo:

**FormExcel.vue**

```
<template>
<form>
    <div class="form-group-row">
        <h3>Subir Excel</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" name="import_file" class="form-control">

        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Subir" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</template>
```

La parte del script lo tengo en blanco. Esto ya que estuve buscando en muchos lados, blogs etc y no encontraba un modo para tenerlo con algo.

Estoy usando la librería de LaravelExcel de Maatwebsite y siguiendo su documentación estoy realizando la parte del controlador del siguiente modo:

**Controlador:**

```
public function Import.Personas(Request $request){
    Excel::import(new PersonasImport, $request->file('import_file'));

    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

Podrian ayudarme a realizar el import a la base de datos porfavor.

Comment: El problema es en vue o laravel? no me queda claro donde tenes el problema. Si el script esta en blanco como le pasas las cosas de vue a laravel?

Comment: es en vue, no puedo y no tengo idea de como es que lo tengo que mandar.

Comment: fijate axios para mandar cosas de tu front a tu back. tenes que hacer una llamada de algun tipo de tu front a tu back para pasarle los datos.

Comment: encontre un modo para subir archivos con axios, abajo de esto esta una respuesta con todo, gracias ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:**

**FromExcel.vue**

```
<template>
<form>
    <div class="form-group-row">
        <h3>Subir Excel</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group-row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" accept=".XLSX, .CSV" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <button v-on:click="EventSubir()" class="btn btn-primary">Subir</button>
</form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            file: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        EventSubir(){
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', this.file);
            axios
                .post( '/import-excel-personas',
                    formData, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    }
                ).then(function(){
                    console.log('SUCCESS!!');
                })
                .catch(function(){
                    console.log('FAILURE!!');
                });
        },
        handleFileUpload(){
            this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Lo siguiente es como queda el **controlador**:

```
public function ImportPersonas(Request $request){
    Excel::import(new PersonasImport, $request->file('file'));

    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

Recuerden que para entender la parte del controlador lean la documentacion de **LaravelExcel**

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/

Se que hay varios buscando algo similar, espero les ayude.